# Ubuntu user disappeared from machine

Tags: ubuntu, users, home

Unsolved mystery - I was given a coworker's Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS machine and set up my own (sudo/admin) user on there from the command line. I switched to my user (from his sudo/admin user) and confirmed everything was okay using the `groups` command and the `/etc/passwd` file looked great. After months of everything working perfectly, a power outage shut down the machine for the first time since I inherited it.

After booting, my new user disappeared. It's not in the /etc/passwd file and there is no entry in the /home directory. I created the user the same as I did before, and there were no errors to indicate that the user still existed.

What happened?

As requested, here is the output of

```
olduser@machine:~$ ls -lait /home 
total 16 
3408126 drwxr-xr-x 2 newuser newuser 4096 Nov 20 10:28 newuser 
3407873 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 20 10:28 . 
3407874 drwxr-xr-x 36 coworker coworker 4096 Nov 20 10:00 bvillupu 
2 drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 Oct 3 2012 .. 
3408259 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Aug 9 2012 .directory -> /etc/kubuntu-default-settings/directory-home
```

Comment: What does the command line give back? ls -lait /home/

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux @k0d3x! This is really a comment, not an answer. Answers should only be used to provide actual _answers_ not to ask for clarification. If you spend some more time on the site, you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges) to leave comments on posts. In the meantime, I have converted your answer to a comment.

Comment: @sg Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question but if the user was missing from `/etc/passwd` then someone with `sudo/root` access at some time deleted the user. Being that the user's home directory was also missing gives me the impression that someone ran a not only did a `userdel` they did a `rm -rf /home/user`. That implies that there was intent to delete. You can check the `secure` file in `/var/log` to see if, in fact, someone deleted the user.

Comment: There is no /var/log/secure file, but I did use grep on /var/log/* to look for 'myuser', 'delete', and 'deluser' and came up with nothing

Comment: I thought the /var/log/secure was univeral but it may just be a RHEL based thing.

Comment: Make sure to do a `grep -r myuser /var/log/` to ensure grep goes recursively down the directories. If `deluser` wasn't used and the user was manually deleted from `/etc/passwd` then there won't be a log anyway.

Comment: Right, used -r and got nothin', I also checked crontabs for anything weird but there weren't any scripts running there either.